# Finding features that influence net revenue

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning

Using machine learning I would like to identify features that influence `net revenue` and make conclusions from data based on that. The data set is a car sharing company data (like Turo). Data set contains ~80000 rows 14 columns.

I have difficulty to build a EDA especially with ML algorithm to use to find out features that influence on `net_revenue`.

[image]

#What I did so far

1. I did correlation matrix analysis on this data and find out `'youth driver fee'` has the most `correlated` feature to `'net_revenue'` (
   I kept `make` and `model` columns out of the analysis because there are so many makes and models and its hard to predict their effect on the `net_revenue`)
2. I wanted to see this correlation is relevant with some ML algorithms such as `Logistic regression` and `Randomforest`. To further applying RandomForest ML to verify this correlation I converted categorical variables (payment_type, returning_guest and returning_host) to the dummy variables (0's and 1's)

So I tried to apply these two models by following this [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/predict-employee-turnover-with-python-da4975588aa3)

LogisticRegression

```
cols=['driver_age', 'completed_trips', 'vehicle_price', 'lead_time', 'trip_length', 
              'trip_revenue', 'youth_driver_fee', 'insurance_fee', 'delivery_fee', 'returning_quest_First_time','returning_quest_Repeat','returning_host_First_time','returning_host_repeat']
    
            X=data[cols]
            y=data['net_revenue']

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

*default settings of LogisticRegression

*LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class=’ovr’, n_jobs=1, penalty=’l2', random_state=None, solver=’liblinear’, tol=0.0001, verbose=0, warm_start=False)*

**The `IPython` notebook freezes after executing the code above and it looks like it would never output something.So I have to restart the kernel.

RandomForest

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Same problem!

My Questions:

1. How can I a ML model for finding features that influence net revenue? Is there any resource that the same problem addressed? Kaggle competitions definitely fine or maybe a medium post.

I found one dataset to predict features on target value but target value look like categorical mine is continuous.
from https://www.kaggle.com/prasadkevin/prediction-of-quality-of-wine

2. to use `LogisticRegression` and `RandomForest`, has `net_revenue` to be categorical variable?
3. Do you happen to know any similar dataset on Kaggle? because I could not find any correlated ML flow like this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

When using any machine learning model, you have to convert every categorical variable to a dummy variable, not just for Random Forests.

You are using `RandomForestClassifier` for a regression problem, which is not what you want. Instead use `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor`.

Your machine learning models are probably running if no errors are being thrown. Since you have 80,000 rows it may just take a while. When you define your models, define them as

```
logreg = LogisticRegression(verbose=1)
```

and

```
rf = RandomForestRegressor(verbose=1)
```

If the models are running they will print out their progress so you can see what is going on.